# In Android are there any disadvantages to using multiple content providers

Tags: android, performance, android-contentprovider

I am currently working with an application that has one content provider that provides interactions for around 10 tables.  In my quest to add unit testing to this project I was going to break up this singular provider into multiple providers (maybe one per table) to try and isolate functionality into distinct classes/providers.

Before I went through this process, I was curious if there was any disadvantage to doing this, like a performance hit for the overhead of managing many providers as opposed to one.  Is there any documented side effects of having multiple content providers?

Comment: You wana use differnt database for single table, too? Main question should be: what adv. will you get by divide single cp to multiple cps

Comment: @Selvin The tables are all being stored in the same database and I wasn't planing on changing that, would that be a problem?

Comment: Then you will face problem with multiple access to the same db file from different cps

Comment: @Selvin if I use an Abstract Factory pattern for the SQLiteOpenHelper won't that prevent any access issues across multiple providers? Something like whats described here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

Comment: Nice article btw... Yes it will prevent any access issues... Still i really do not see the point for multiple cps for one db... Next problem is modification of the same table from different cps... ContentObserver are based on uris...lets assume that you have com.example.books and com.example.newspapers cps both returns data from own tables and few columns from common table(fx publishers)  ... In which cp you will update publishers and which uris will be notified?

Comment: @Selvin I'm planning on breaking it apart by its functionality not necessary by table. So any tables that interact will be kept in the same provider.  For example if I was storing books (with tables: book, author, publisher) and movies (with tables: movie, actor, director) I would have 2 providers; 1 for books, 1 for movies.  My thought process is just to make the code cleaner and more focused instead of a giant switch statement on URIs for every table I have in my database.  Maybe the answer is that I should break the tables into separate databases in addition to different content providers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37607/discussion-between-stackjp-and-selvin)